# How do I reset Eclipse back to default settings on Macbook

Tags: eclipse

I somehow messed up the package explorer settings for Eclipse on my Macbook Pro. I can't do my homework until I get this issue figured out. All i want to do is reset all the settings back to the default settings. 
Macbook Pro using Eclipse
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Comment: You mean reset your perspectives?

Comment: @Vikram will reseting the perspective reset how the package explorer looks?

Comment: yes resetting the perspective will reset the package explorer as well. BTW did you installed eclipsecolorthemes?

Comment: @Vikram I don't know if I've installed eclipsecolorthemes. How do check and what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Eclipse explorer looks messy. Resetting package Explorer or perspective

`Window -> Reset Perspective`

If the above doesn't work, You can probably clear your meta data for resetting everything

`rm -rv $WORKSPACE_DIR/.metadata/` After this restart your eclipse

Comment: Thank you very very much. That was EXACTLY the problem I was trying to solve.